# Set value of file input to Base64 encoded image

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, input, base64

I want my service to test a certain file input by uploading Base64 encoded image. Is this possible with Selenium?

Lets say i have:

```
<input type="file">
```

I know that for regular file upload, i have to set file path for this input, but what about Base64 encoded images?

Edit: Language is Python

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified a language. This answer is in Java.

Encode the image to base64 and upload it.

For file reading, you have to add "Apache Commons IO" libraries.

```
    String filePath = "F:\\cat.jpg";

    // Encode image
    byte[] fileContent = new byte[0];
    try {
        fileContent = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(filePath));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileContent);

    // Upload image
    WebElement uploadElement = driver.findElement(By.id("upload_element_id"));

    uploadElement.sendKeys(encodedString);
```